# Open GUI in bash on windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

On bash in windows 10 , I can navigate to the desired file and for now I can edit them with vi, but for ease of use I want to edit them with text editor like gedit or sublime text. But I can't do that e.g if I try to open a file with gedit it says "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"